# Example of infinite , compact, path connected metric space $X$ which is homeomorphic to $X \times X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, path-connected

Does there exist a compact, path connected metric space $X$, with more than one point , such that $X \times X$ is homeomorphic with $X$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consider e.g. $X=[0,1]^\omega$.

Comment: Just on a side note ... In your case , is $X \times X$  bijectively isometric with $X$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure right now that we can pose such a metric on $X$..

Comment: $X \times X$ is metrizable if $X$ is ... just take the taxicab type metric  ...

Comment: Let me make it more explicit by asking :does there exist a metric $d$ on $X$ and $e$ on $X \times X$ in your example such that those metrics give the usual topology on $X$ and $X\times X$ resp. such that with those metrics, the spaces are bijectively isometric ?

Comment: I don't know.. $ $